# Disabling/Enabling html elements with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm starting to learn AngularJS for a web app, and I have an issue with understanding the workflow of the framework.

I have 2 dropdowns :

```
<select class='selectorDropdown' ng-model='selectedElement' ng-change='selectedElementChange()'>
    <option value='0' disabled selected>Option0
    <option value='1'>Option1
    <option value='2'>Option2
</select>

<select class='selectorDropdown' id='selector2' disabled>
    <option value='3'>Option1
    <option value='4'>Option2
</select>
```

I want the second dropdown to be enabled only after another option than Option0 has been selected on the first dropdown. So here's my Javascript code :

```
$scope.selectedElementChange = function() {
    document.getElementById('selector2').disabled = true;
}
```

So far, it looks like regular Javascript (and I'm manipulating the DOM), so I guess this is not really the way AngularJS was mean to be used. Could someone help me understand the "correct" way to do this with AngularJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, without writing a single line of JavaScript:

```
<select class='selectorDropdown' id='selector2' ng-disabled='selectedElement == "0"'>
    <option value='3'>Option1
    <option value='4'>Option2
</select>
```

You don't need the `ng-change` either. Angular takes care of updating the model when the first selector changes, and then runs a digest loop to update anything else.

You also need to initialize `selectedElement` somewhere; Angular doesn't take its value from the fact that you wrote `selected` on the `Option0` element. The cleanest way is to do it in the controller:

```
$scope.selectedElement = "0";
```

The quick and dirty way is `ng-init`:

```
<select ... ng-init='selectedElement = "0"'>
```

[Plunk.](https://plnkr.co/edit/ihEis4FaVfimhufKjuSO?p=preview)